# How to create a citation that doesn't change when compiled?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am compiling a bibliography using a BibTeX file. When I compile it into my LaTeXPDF file it changes my citations in the reference section. For example it abbreviates the author's name. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

Yo can use different styles for your bibtex:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Bibliography_styles

I believe that you are using `abbrv`, try using `plain`!